# Laravel routes issue with Lowercase

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I am trying to setup this route

```
http://test.localhost.com/doctor/updateschedule
```

My code in Routes file is

```
Route::resource('/doctor/updateschedule', 'Doctor\DoctorController@doctorSchedule');
```

But this does not work, It only works if I Use an Uppercase

```
http://test.localhost.com/Doctor/updateschedule
```

And in Routes,

```
Route::resource('/Doctor/updateschedule', 'Doctor\DoctorController@doctorSchedule');
```

There is nothing in the Controller's action, just an echo "Hello".
it only works with an uppercase **/Doctor/updateschedule**

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how can i make it work for lowercases?

Comment: Try removing the first slash so that you have `Route::resource('doctor/updateschedule', 'Doctor\DoctorController@doctorSchedule');`

Comment: Sounds like you have another route that conflicts with the lowercase `doctor`. Can you please post all routes that start with `doctor` (or `/doctor`)?

Comment: @V4n1ll4 i just tried, Didn't work.

Comment: @lukasgeiter No, I Double checked, I haven't used the same route anywhere else in the file. This is unique.

Comment: What error do you get if you go to `doctor/updateschedule` (all lowercase)

Comment: @V4n1ll4 I don't get any error, i just get a blank page. If u use Upper case, then i get the "HELLO" that i have echo'ed in the function in the controller. I think this is not some error, it might be some default Laravel settings that is not documented.

Comment: Have you checked the Laravel logs in `storage/logs/laravel.log`?  Also, do you have any middleware setup in the controller?

Comment: @V4n1ll4 I just checked the logs after you just mentioned it. But I don't see any new entries in the log after I hit the URL. But then again, I am not sure what I should be looking for in the Logs. Also, I have two middlewares for the route, one is the default "Auth" and the other one is a custom one, "doctor".

Comment: Are you able to post your entire routes file?

Comment: Something with your route is wrong, you can't add a resource route to a specific controller method (`doctorSchedule`) just a controller class. Are you sure you shouldn't be using a simple `Route::get()` for this?

Comment: @lukasgeiter It doesn't work for that as well, even for get or post routes. The same thing happens, I get a blank page.

Comment: @V4n1ll4 Yes, middlewares are working fine, and as I mentioned, Everything works fine if I use an uppercase "D" in my routes.

Comment: Does this affect other routes too?

Comment: I'm convinced it's either the Routes file or a misconfigured server, but this would affect other routes too.

Comment: Just a stupid question, but did you install that Doctor namespace in the composer.json?

Comment: @AdityaGiri Dude, not everyone is a pro, we all start from scratch. Something that u know might not be known to everyone, that is why Stackoverflow exists.

Comment: Alright let's simplify. Do you have `Doctor` namespace in the file `composer.json` at `psr-4` in `autoload`?